# Error decrypting mime content - ASN1 bad tag value met

Tags: c#, mimekit

I wrote a function to create a mime message and encrypt the content with users public cert that's stored in the cert store while the private keys are stored on my smart card. My function simply saves the pkcs7mime content to a file.
I have another test function, which simply reads the file and tries to decrypt the content. However, when I try to decrypt, I get the error: ASN1 bad tag value met.

My encryption function code:

```
private static void EncryptMime()
    {
        MimeMessage mm = new MimeMessage();
        var ctx = new WindowsSecureMimeContext();
        mm.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("Bob", "Bob@diamondsg.onmicrosoft.com"));
        mm.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("Alice", "Alice@diamondsg.onmicrosoft.com"));

        mm.Subject = "Smime Test";

        mm.Body = new TextPart("plain")
        {
            Text = @"This is a test."
        };

        var signer = mm.From.Mailboxes.FirstOrDefault();
        var recipients = mm.To.Mailboxes.AsEnumerable();
        ApplicationPkcs7Mime p7m = ApplicationPkcs7Mime.SignAndEncrypt(ctx, signer, DigestAlgorithm.Sha1, recipients, mm.Body);

        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        p7m.WriteTo(ms, true);
        byte[] bytes = ms.GetBuffer();
        File.WriteAllBytes("smime.p7m", bytes);
    }
```

Here is my decrypt function:

```
private static void DecryptMime()
    {

        CryptographyContext.Register(typeof(WindowsSecureMimeContext));

        string messagetext = "";
        // Read the p7m file           
        byte[] bytes = 
        File.ReadAllBytes("smime.p7m");
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
        ApplicationPkcs7Mime p7m = new ApplicationPkcs7Mime(SecureMimeType.EnvelopedData, ms);
        // WindowsSecureMimeContext ctx = new WindowsSecureMimeContext(StoreLocation.CurrentUser);

        if (p7m != null && p7m.SecureMimeType == SecureMimeType.EnvelopedData)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Decrypting message...");
            try
            {
                p7m = p7m.Decrypt() as ApplicationPkcs7Mime;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error decrypting: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        if (p7m != null && p7m.SecureMimeType == SecureMimeType.CompressedData)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Decompressing message...");
            p7m = p7m.Decompress() as ApplicationPkcs7Mime;
        }

        if (p7m != null && p7m.SecureMimeType == SecureMimeType.SignedData)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Verifying message...");
            p7m.Verify(out MimeEntity entity);
            MimeMessage mm = new MimeMessage(entity);
            messagetext = mm.GetTextBody(MimeKit.Text.TextFormat.Text);
            Console.WriteLine("Decrypted Message: " + messagetext);
        }           
    }
```

Edit:
I tried isolating the issue by using the following code:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        p7m.WriteTo(ms);    
ApplicationPkcs7Mime new_p7m = new ApplicationPkcs7Mime(SecureMimeType.EnvelopedData, ms);  

        if (new_p7m != null && new_p7m.SecureMimeType == SecureMimeType.EnvelopedData)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Decrypting message...");
            try
            {
                new_p7m = new_p7m.Decrypt() as ApplicationPkcs7Mime;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error decrypting: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

So the problem seems to start as early as the WriteTo() function...

Update #2:
Ok, so I did a toString on both the p7m and the new_p7m object. Apparently, the content is different...

```
p7m: Content-Type: application/pkcs7-mime; smime-type=enveloped-data;
    name=smime.p7m
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=smime.p7m
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

MIIOOwYJKoZIhvcNAQcDoIIOLDCCDigCAQIxggEwMIIBLAIBAoAU2NQqDvYHJuMeC27IpyiV
....

New p7m: Content-Type: application/pkcs7-mime; smime-type=enveloped-data;
    name=smime.p7m
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=smime.p7m
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

Q29udGVudC1UeXBlOiBhcHBsaWNhdGlvbi9wa2NzNy1taW1lOyBzbWltZS10eXBlPWVudmVs
....
```

To, somehow the actual content is changing... very strange...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm betting that your code to save the content to disk is writing a corrupt file:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
p7m.WriteTo(ms, true);
byte[] bytes = ms.GetBuffer();
File.WriteAllBytes("smime.p7m", bytes);
```

The problem with the above code is that `GetBuffer()` returns more bytes than are actually used by the memory stream in most cases. The above logic will also save the content in base64 which is probably not what you want. The following code snippet will decode the base64 content into the smime.p7m file:

```
using (var stream = File.Create ("smime.p7m"))
    p7m.Content.DecodeTo (stream);
```

Then, to reconstruct the MIME part back for decrypting, do this:

```
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes ("smime.p7m");
var ms = new MemoryStream (bytes);
var p7m = new ApplicationPkcs7Mime (SecureMimeType.EnvelopedData, ms);
```

The problem you were facing is that the content was base64 encoded before and it should not have been.

Of course, unless there's really a need to save just the raw content and then re-construct the application/pkcs7-mime part the hard way, why not just save the entire MIME part like this?

```
using (var stream = File.Create ("smime.p7m"))
    p7m.WriteTo (stream);
```

And then re-load it like this:

```
using (var stream = File.OpenRead ("smime.p7m"))
    p7m = (ApplicationPkcs7Mime) MimeEntity.Load (stream);
```

Then you don't have to worry about getting things wrong.

Comment: I tried both ToArray() and the code you wrote, both still give me the same error. But to test your suspicion, I tried to decrypt the p7m immediately after encrypting, and it seems to be able to decrypt correctly. So probably the way I'm writing the buffer to file is wrong.

Comment: I updated my answer. The content you were saving was base64 encoded and you do not want that.

Comment: Awesome, that worked. So that means the content was base64 encoded in the first place? Is there a way that I can set the encoding?

Comment: Yes: `p7m.ContentTransferEncoding = ContentEncoding.Base64;`

Comment: So if I set the ContentEncoding to Default, the WriteTo() function will then work as expected?

Comment: It should, yes, but in general, don't do that. Use `part.Content.DecodeTo()` instead of trying to outsmart MimeKit. Also: why are you saving just the content anyway? Why not the entire MIME part? It would be way easier.

Comment: So basically, this code that I'm writing is part of a larger project. I'm building a plugin that retrieves just p7m file attachment from web mail (e.g. OWA) for decryption. Similarly, when I encrypt the message body, I want to construct just the content and attach it as a p7m attachment. It's a kinda strange requirement... But the email client that I'm sending this email to is able to recognize the .p7m attachment.

Comment: Okay, I guess that makes sense then. I'd still recommend using the `p7m.Content.DecodeTo(stream);` method, though.